# R not consistently converting time around DST time change

Tags: r, date, timezone, dst

Using R on Windows Machine

```
as.POSIXct('2018-11-04 01:30:00', tz = 'America/Chicago')
# "2018-11-04 01:30:00 CDT"

as.POSIXct('2018-11-04 01:40:00', tz = 'America/Chicago')
# "2018-11-04 01:40:00 CST"
```

I understand these times are ambiguous (can technically be CDT or CST) and can be difficult for R to interpret. However, the randomness of these results make it difficult to convert times during these periods. Is there a way around this that allows for more consistent results?

Answer (score 1):

If you'll look at the integer representation you'll notice:

```
# divide by 60 to convert to minutes from seconds
as.integer(as.POSIXct('2018-11-04 01:30:00', tz = 'America/Chicago'))/60
# [1] 25688550

as.integer(as.POSIXct('2018-11-04 01:40:00', tz = 'America/Chicago'))/60
# [1] 25688620
```

These are 70 minutes apart, meaning that the latter corresponds to what would have been 2:40 if CDT continued; this seems pretty consistent to me. I was unable to find any reference on a quick search on exactly what the details are of the daylight savings switch for `America/Chicago` timezone in particular.

Also, you might consider looking at the `POSIXlt` representation in this case:

```
dput(as.POSIXlt('2018-11-04 01:30:00', tz = 'America/Chicago'))
# structure(list(sec = 0, min = 30L, hour = 1L, mday = 4L, mon = 10L, 
#     year = 118L, wday = 0L, yday = 307L, isdst = 1L, zone = "CDT", 
#     gmtoff = NA_integer_), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago")

dput(as.POSIXlt('2018-11-04 01:40:00', tz = 'America/Chicago'))
# structure(list(sec = 0, min = 40L, hour = 1L, mday = 4L, mon = 10L, 
#     year = 118L, wday = 0L, yday = 307L, isdst = 0L, zone = "CST", 
#     gmtoff = NA_integer_), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago")
```

Note the difference in `isdst` between the two objects...

To proceed, we'd really need to track down an authoritative source on how CDT/CST are demarcated. But FWIW, the exact time of the switch appears to be `1:30:05`:

```
as.POSIXct('2018-11-04 01:30:05', tz = 'America/Chicago')
# [1] "2018-11-04 01:30:05 CDT"

as.POSIXct('2018-11-04 01:30:06', tz = 'America/Chicago')
# [1] "2018-11-04 01:30:06 CST"
```

(to figure this out, I looked at the output of:)

```
with(expand.grid(second = 0:59, minute = 30:40),
     as.POSIXct(sprintf('2018-11-04 01:%02d:%02d', minute, second),
                tz = 'America/Chicago'))
```

Comment: Some references for you [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/chicago) and [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/chicago).  Also, you can read the implementation and comments in the [northamerica](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2018g/northamerica) file of the TZ database (Zone [`America/Chicago`](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2018g/northamerica#L394-L401) and Rule [`US`](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2018g/northamerica#L150-L163))

Comment: To be clear, the transition is not at 1:30:05.  On November 4th 2018, as the local time in Chicago approached 02:00, it reset to 01:00, repeating the hour from 01:00 through 01:59.  In other words, the clock ticked `01:58 CDT`, `01:59 CDT`, `01:00 CST`, `01:01 CST`...